# Crashes on some posts

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

On some posts, like "How quickly will government realize I am printing money?" on World Building, the app will crash.

Here is a list of posts that I've crashed on and recorded so far:

- [How quickly will government realize that I am printing money?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66603/11203)
- [The sum of series with natural logarithm: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)^2}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2083217/278116)
- [How did wireless telegraphy reach so far?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/278419)
- [The A. G. R. A. flash drive](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/66160)
- [How much memory does int x[10] allocate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41467933/436524)

I don't really see a pattern among these, but I have a feeling that it's triggered by image embedding. There aren't any images in some of these, though.

App/Device Info:

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6
- OS Version: Version 8.4 (Build 12H143)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the problematic posts?

Comment: I can't repro on http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/66603, but I'm using 1.6.3 from TestFlight.

Comment: Works fine for me on @JAL suggested link. 1.6.2.5 iPad with iOS 10.2

Comment: @JAL your link does crash, that's the one. I'll edit it in later.

Comment: Can't repro here (1.6.3 on iPhone 6S)

Comment: @JAL I've added some more posts. I'll update it as I crash.

Comment: Does it crash every time? Do you do anything in particular? Can't repro on any of those posts here.

Comment: It crashes every single time, sometimes I need to scroll down about 5-20 pixels for it to trigger.

Comment: Can you provide a device or crash log?  You can get them from Xcode -> Window -> Devices -> [Your Device] -> View Device Logs

Comment: All of your links work for me. Do you want to update OS? :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I run jailbroken (I realize this _could_ be the problem, but I doubt it) and it's simply not possible for me to upgrade and keep everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, that was my fault completely, but it's over now.

This was caused by a bug in iOS 8's `CGPathAddArcToPoint`, triggered by a single Winter Bash hat.  By the time I noticed, Winter Bash was almost over and there were only 15 affected users, so I just let it run out without fixing it.

To fix this going forward, iOS 8 (and maybe 9) won't be participating in 2017's Winter Bash and I'll make an effort to test the hats on more devices.